# Can I get help formatting my future dates javascript?

Tags: javascript

Working on a weather app that includes a 5 day forecast and I would like the dates displayed. I cant figure out how to format it to just month, date and year (ex: July 23rd 2020) which should be 'll'. It's still showing as "Jul 23 2020 Fri Jul 24 2020 19:54:06 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) Day" instead of formatting properly.

Here is my HTML:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col" id = "one" ></div>
        <div class="col" id = "two" > Day Two</div>
        <div class="col" id = "three" > Day Three</div>
        <div class="col" id = "four" > Day Four</div>
        <div class="col" id = "five" > Day Five</div>
    </div>
```

And here is my javascript:

```
const tomorrow = new Date()

tomorrow.setDate(new Date(ll).getDate() + 1);

var one = document.getElementById('one');
one.innerHTML = tomorrow;
```

Comment: where did you use moment?

Comment: want you to change your code using moment?

Comment: I thought I used the moment format but I guess not? I dont mind changing to moment if its easier. Or if I could get help formatting it with standard javascript that works too.

Comment: i added an answer below.  If it's not what you are looking for, moment works, but it's so limited that we are using Kendo date tools instead.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the format you needed is always like you mentioned

```
function format(date){
    var months=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
    var suffices={_0:'th',_1:'st',_2:'nd',_3:'rd',_4:'th',_5:'th',_6:'th',_7:'th',_8:'th',_9:'th',_11:'th',_12:'th',_13:'th'};
    return months[date.getMonth()]+' '+date.getDate()+(suffices['_'+date.getDate()] || suffices['_'+date.getDate()%10])+' '+date.getFullYear();

}
```

**Usage**

```
format(new Date())//returns "Jul 24th 2020"
format(new Date(2020,11,13))//returns "Dec 13th 2020"
```

Comment: So I added your function in before the code I already had and its not changing anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: you need to pass `tomorrow ` to the given function. This will give you a formatted date string. Isn't that you wanted?

Comment: I'm not understanding your question. My goal is to display it on my screen as July 23rd 2020 (or whichever the current day is).

Comment: Your question says you had trouble formatting the dates. The fn i gave you only deals with that. in your case you need to pass `tomorrow` to this fn and the returned value to be assigned as `one.innerHTML = format(tomorrow);`

Answer (score 0):

if you are simply wanting the left side of the date, all you have to do is parse the date string.  Something like this:

```
var mydate = new Date().toString().split(' ');
var formattedDate = b =  a[1] + " " + a[2] + " " + a[3];
```

if you're insistent on the "rd" after your number, that will require a lookup table like in some other answers.  This code splits the string into an array of strings by space then combines the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th elements into a new string.

Comment: I'm entering it in like so and its not working. Am i plugging it in wrong?                             var mydate = new Date().toString().split(' ');
    var formattedDate = b =  a[1] + " " + a[2] + " " + a[3];

    const tomorrow = mydate;

    tomorrow.setDate(mydate.getDate() + 1);

    var one = document.getElementById('one');
    one.innerHTML = tomorrow;